# Remove non-duplicate lines in Linux

Tags: linux, awk, text-manipulation, uniq

how can I remove non-duplicate lines from text file using any linux program linke sed, awk or any other?

Example:

```
abc
bbc
abc
bbc
ccc
bbc
```

Result:

```
abc
bbc
abc
bbc
bbc
```

Second list have removed ccc because it didn't have duplicate lines.

Is it also possible to remove lines, that are non-duplicate AND lines that have only 2 duplicates, and leave those who have more then 2 duplicates lines?

Comment: Is the order important?  Also, are the lines all the same length, or what pattern do they have?

Comment: Lines have different lenght, order is not important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solutions posted by others do not work on my Debian Jessie: they keep a **single** copy of any duplicate line, while it is my understanding of the OP that **all** copies of the duplicate lines are to be kept. If I have understood the OP right, then ...

1. The following command

   ```
   awk '!seen[$0]++' file
   ```

   removes all duplicate lines.
2. The following command

   ```
   awk 'seen[$0]++' file
   ```

   outputs all the duplicates, but not the original copy: *i.e.*, if a line appears *n* times, it outputs the line *n-1* times.
3. Then the command

   ```
   awk 'seen[$0]++' file > temp && awk '!seen[$0]++' file >> temp
   ```

   solves your problem. The lines are not in the original order.
4. If you want lines which have two or more duplicates, you can now iterate the above:

   ```
   awk 'seen[$0]++' file | awk 'seen[$0]++' > temp
   ```

   keeps *n-2* copies of the lines which have *n>1* duplicates. Now

   ```
   awk '!seen[$0]++' temp > temp1
   ```

   removes all duplicate lines from the temp file, and you can now obtain what you wish (*i.e.* only the lines with *n>1* duplicates) as follows:

   ```
   cat temp1 >> temp; cat temp1 >> temp
   ```
5. If you need to do this for lines which appear *N* or more times, the following command

   ```
     awk 'seen[$0]++ && seen[$0] > N' file
   ```

   is simpler than chaining *N* times the command `awk 'seen[$0]++' file`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `sort` & `uniq` commands for this.

If your data in abc.txt file, then;

```
cat abc.txt |sort|uniq -d
```

Out put will be;

```
abc 
bbc
```

Comment: This is does not match the desired output

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @UUU doesn't keep sort order. To keep sort order, use the following instead:

```
 printf '%s\n' abc bbc abc bbc ccc bbc | \
     nl -nrz     | \
     sort -k2    | \
     uniq -f1 -D | \
     sort        | \
     cut -f2
```

1. The `printf` command simply reproduces the input.
2. `nl` command appends line numbers with leading zeros to allow for `sort` without the `-V` flag.
3. `sort` command sorts by the 2nd field. By default fields are separated by blanks.
4. `uniq` command identifies unique adjacent lines (which is why you have to sort first) and `-f1` skips the first field which is the line number.
5. `sort` again to restore the original order.
6. `cut` to remove the leading line numbers.